# Entity Framework 4 + CTP 4 + Oracle ODP make them work together?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I am trying to set up an application that uses (on framework 4.0):

- Entity FrameWork 4
- CTP code first with EF support
- Oracle 11g Database with Oracle ado.net provider (ef support still in beta version)
- Silverlight 4 (but this is irrelevant)

...all togheter. it's crazy or make sense?

using sql server of course no problems, but with oracle music changes...

I'm trying not to use third-party providers or nHibernate ORM (i need EF!)

Is there anyone who already done this successfully?
I have already attempted with poor results, maybe someone has done it Ascolta
in the right way. If yes, how?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

@Tridus

I GOT this error when i switch to Oracle provider:

[Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed]

in VS i can see "Oracle Database (Oracle ODP.NET)" so Provider is installed.

in *web.config* connection string is

`<connectionStrings>
        <add name="BlogContext" connectionString="Data Source=HR/******@127.0.0.1//XE" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection,Oracle.DataAccess,Version=2.112.2.30,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </connectionStrings>`

the only thing I noticed is that i have installed Oracle Express 10gg and not the full 11g.

Any suggestion to figure out my issue?

Comment: Code first is already RTW http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/04/19/using-code-first-through-nuget.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm using EF 4.1 (the release version of your CTP) with the Oracle beta 1 EF driver using DB first and with a couple of known issues aside it works well. They haven't indicated if Code First is going to be supported, but they also haven't said it's not supported. Beta 2 of the driver is apparently coming out sometime in June, we might know more then.

So first I'd suggest you update to the release version of EF 4.1, then try it. If you still can't get it to work, [this thread on Oracle's forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2209863&tstart=45) has the developer's email address in it. He says there to email him with Code First questions, so that's your best bet right now.